# Lifetime of const reference variable not extended

Tags: c++, reference, lifetime, string-literals

Binding a temporary to a const reference extends its lifetime; cf. [GotW #88](http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/).

Why does not this work on this snippet? Live [here](http://ideone.com/h1sx7V).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct A {
    A() : s("abc") {}
    const std::string& s;
};

struct B {
    const std::string& s = "def";
};

int main() {
    A a;
    std::cout << a.s << std::endl;
    B b;
    std::cout << b.s << std::endl;
}
```

Bonus question: How to trigger a warning with gcc?

Comment: Quoting the GotW you linked: "Note this only applies to stack-based references. It doesn’t work for references that are members of objects".

Comment: Yes, it is what R Sahu mentioned in his answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the article that you linked to, you will find:

> (Note this only applies to stack-based references. It doesn’t work for references that are members of objects.)

That's why the references in `a` and `b` are not valid. They don't extend the life of the temporaries.

Comment: I had not read it in full for a long time, and forgot that point. Thank you!

Comment: Would you know how to trigger a warning for this?

Comment: With g++, `-Wextra` produces: `warning: a temporary bound to ‘A::s’ only persists until the constructor exits [-Wextra]`

Comment: @RSahu If you compile this code with g++, or MSVS 2011/2014/2017 it compiles and runs perfectly. I don't even get warnings. Do I not understand something? Is it UB?

Comment: @Nik-Lz, yes it is UB.

Answer (score 3):

From C++14 [class.temporary]/5:

> The temporary to which the reference is bound or the temporary that is the complete object of a subobject to which the reference is bound persists
>   for the lifetime of the reference **except**:
>
> - A temporary bound to a reference member in a constructor’s *ctor-initializer* persists until the constructor exits.
> - [...]

Answer (score 1):

cppreference.com says:

> a temporary bound to a reference member in a constructor initializer
>   list persists only until the constructor exits, not as long as the
>   object exists.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization

Comment: Thanks, I very much prefer the wording of cppreference to the standard’s. There is a note saying until C++14, however, and I compiled my code with the gcc flag `-std=c++14`. Do you know what is different?

Comment: Your welcome!

Wikipedia says C++14 is the informal name for the most recent revision of the C++ ISO standard.
[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B14]

I guess it means that the rule we are talking about will be changed in the next formal standard or it is very probable to be changed. But I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

The lifetime is only extended to the end of the compiler generator constructor for `B`.  When the constructor returns, the temporary string created to hold "def" will be destroyed leaving you with a dangling reference.

Comment: Why so? The reference `s` does not go out of scope and has the same lifetime as the struct.

Comment: Because of how inline initializers are handled by the compiler.  A constructor will be generated to do the initialization and that's the scope that has the lifetime of the temporary.